# How to use .so files in Android

Tags: java, android, c++, c, sqlite

I am tring to add a C++ library into my Android project, but I keep getting the error:

```
Could not get unknown property 'jniLibs' for source set 'main' of type org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultSourceSet.
```

The project attempts to use a **.so** library of SQLite *( [amalgamation](https://www.sqlite.org/amalgamation.html))*.

How can I include the .so lib in my project and link it successfully to be able to call its functions?

Thank you all in advance.

**My build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path 'CMakeLists.txt'
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['src/main/jniLibs']
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        jniLibs.srcDirs = ['src/main/jniLibs']
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

1. remove config in build.gradle. This path is the default value of jniLibs, no customer config is needed.

   sourceSets {
       main {
           jniLibs.srcDirs = ['src/main/jniLibs']
       }
   }

or try with this config

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        jniLibs.srcDir(['src/main/jniLibs'])
    }
}
```

2. copy the so file into `app/src/main/jniLibs`.
3. add the JNI java interface jar into your dependency.
4. System.LoadLibrary(libName) // for example you put xxx.so into jniLibs folder. here would be System.LoadLibrary("xxx")
5. Use the native method in JNI java class to call so method.

Comment: Thank you for the reply @xingjiu. With that I get the error: `Could not list contents of '/project/src/main/jniLibs/libsqlite3.so'. Couldn't follow symbolic link.
` Could you please advise.

Comment: A pure clean build may help, symbolic link always caused by some middle compile files.